# do_rootfs error when bitbake sdcard image

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, disk-partitioning, imx6

I have created sdcard images for imx6 with Yocto project. I try to create an image with "bitbake core-image-x11" command but I keep having these errores.I think the first proble is about disk partition and the other problem is about do_rootfs function. Please do help if you have solved this.[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xboI7.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/xboI7.png)

Comment: Please show the steps you followed to get the errors. your local.conf will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

The error is shown in your screenshot.

> /usr/IMX/fsl-community-bsp-new/build/tmp/deploy/images/imx6qsabresd/zImage-imx6qsabresd.bin: No such file or directory.

You need to ensure that this file exists in your deploy directory prior to executing the do_rootfs to create your sdcard image.

Please post your .bbclass or .bbappend file, or local.conf so we can obtain more information.